# Why can't I pass a variable to VARCHAR(str_len) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

After years of doing MSSQL, I'm back with MySQL and it's quite challenging. My noob question is, why can't I pass a variable to `VARCHAR(string_length)` like the one below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_random_strings` (string_length INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(string_length)
BEGIN
    DECLARE return_string VARCHAR(string_length);

    SELECT concat(
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97)
        )AS Random10CharacterString
    RETURN 1;
END
```

How do you return a string with length based on your parameter?

Comment: I would start by checking out how to define parameters in MySQL. There is a manual around [somewhere](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/)

Comment: I've decided to use the existing get functions in mysql. Just saw them. Thanks @RiggsFolly

Comment: The SQL grammar parser in MySQL doesn't support anything but numeric literals for VARCHAR length. https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L6782-L6786

Comment: You can do this on SQL Server? Pretty sure you cannot, in this instance make it varchar(max) or decide a maximum length, there is zero benefit to trying to dynamically specify the length of a varchar, varchar automatically adjusts its size based the size of the data.

Comment: Hi @Jpsh, you're right. You also cannot do this in sql server. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Thanks also to Bill Karwin. You are all Big Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers, I was making a dummy data generator and I just did it like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `get_varchar`(in_length varchar(2000)) RETURNS varchar(2000) CHARSET utf8mb4
    DETERMINISTIC
RETURN SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR in_length)

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `dummy_insert`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE total_rows INT DEFAULT 100000;
    WHILE counter <= total_rows DO
        INSERT INTO `db`.`table`
        (
        `messageuid`,
        `accountid`,
        `jmessage`,
        `kmessage`,
        `is_sent`,
        `lmessage`
        )
        VALUES
        (
        get_varchar(100),
        get_int(),
        get_varchar(500),
        get_varchar(50),
        get_bit(),
        get_varchar(2000);

    END WHILE;
END
```

Comment: A function which calls `rand` should not be `deterministic`. Check `select get_varchar(5), get_varchar(5)`. I think you'll get the same string twice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to. While `char` is fixed length, `varchar` is ***var***iable length. `varchar(255)` makes a string with a *maximum* of 255 characters.

Unless there's a particular reason you want to restrict the length of the return string, `varchar(255)` is fine. It will only use as much memory as it needs to.

The function can be more simply written like so:

```
create function get_random_strings()
returns varchar(255)
no sql
return concat(
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97),
        char(round(rand()*25)+97)
       );
```

Comment: Thanks @Schwern, I was doing a dummy data generator. I was wondering how to do a function that takes a variable length parameter and returns a string with that length. But I know the difference between a char and a varchar. I just want to make a function that I can call from within an insert statement like this: INSERT INTO `db`.`table` ( `messageuid`,`accountid`, `jmessage`, `kmessage`, `is_sent`, `lmessage` ) VALUES (get_varchar(100),  get_int(),  get_varchar(500),  get_varchar(50),  get_bit(), get_varchar(2000);

Comment: @Sol I thought that might be it. Glad you got it worked out.